# Determine which one more accurate approx $f''(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

Derivatives can be written

1.)
 $$f'(x) = lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
2.)$$f'(x) = lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$

Also $$f''(x) = lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x+h) - f'(x)}{h}$$
So that if we use the number $2.)$ then ***$$f''(x) \approx  \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}$$***
but if we use $1.)$ then 
$$ f''(x) \approx  \frac{f(x+2h) - 2f(x+h) + f(x)}{h^2}$$
My argument is  that the first one for $f''(x)$ is more accurate since the difference is centered, and only depends on the value $f(x)$ in "one $h$ step",or one can achieve the first one by applying Taylors theorem twice.

Is there any other way to prove/show the more accurate one?

Comment: Use Taylor series expansion to show that the first formula (the centred difference) is $O(h^2)$ and the second is only $O(h)$.

Comment: @AndreySokolov how to prove the second one is $O(h)$?

Comment: Got it! thanks @AndreySokolov